# Mi imagen no se ajusta

Tags: html, css, imagen

Tengo una división en mi pantalla y necesito que en la parte derecha la imagen que uso, se ajuste. Sin embargo, lo que realmente hace es poner la imagen y solo mostrar la mitad.

```css
section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  background-color: rgb(239, 231, 226);
  width: 50%;
  font-size: calc(0.5rem + 0.5vw);
  height: 100vh;
}

#right {
  background-image: url(https://www.cic.es/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/industria-4.0-transformacion-digital.jpg);
  background-position: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<section id="About-us">
  <div id="left">
    <h1>Hola</h1>
    <p>My enterprise is a La mayoría de las veces, los elementos absolutamente posicionados que tienen su height y width establecidos en auto son ajustados hasta acomodarse a su contenido. Sin embargo, elementos non-replaced y absolutamente posicionados
      se pueden crear para llenar el espacio vertical disponible, especificando tanto top como bottom, y dejando height sin especificar (es decir, auto). De igual manera se pueden utilizar para llenar el espacio horizontal disponible especificando tanto
      left como right, y dando a width el valor de auto.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: background-size: cover; background-position: center;

Comment: Agrega la parte de left y right pues parece que se desborda una. No estás considerando los márgenes ni los padding

Comment: Hola @lotsoeloso, ¿de qué forma quiere que se ajuste la imagen? 1. A escala, 2. O se recorte con el objeto de que cubra toda la parte derecha.

Answer (score 3):

## Ajuste de imagen

Sea cual fuese la forma en la que desees ajustar la imagen de la derecha deberías realizar algunos ajustes:

Reemplazar en la regla `#right {}`:

```css
#right {
    ...

    background-position: cover;
}
```

Por esta otra:

```css
#right {
    ...

    background-position: center;
}
```

Dado que el valor `cover` no es válida en la propiedad `background-position`.

Ahora bien, ten en cuenta que la sintaxis de la propiedad anterior es:

```css
background-position: x y;
```

Donde `x` es la posición horizontal e `y` es la posición vertical.

Eliminar la propiedad `background-attachment: fixed;` de la regla antes mencionada.

Por último, podrías cambiar a la propiedad `background-size` los valores `100% 100vh` por `contain` o `cover` según el ajuste que desee.

#### Caso 1:

Para el primer caso de ajuste de imagen tenemos el siguiente ejemplo:

```css
section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  background-color: rgb(239, 231, 226);
  width: 50%;
  font-size: calc(0.5rem + 0.5vw);
  height: 100vh;
}

#right {
  background-image: url(https://www.cic.es/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/industria-4.0-transformacion-digital.jpg);
  
  /* Se reemplazó «cover» por «center» */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
  /* Se elimina esta propiedad: */
  /* background-attachment: fixed; */
  
  /* Se reemplazó 100% 100vh por contain
     el primer caso */
  background-size: contain;
  
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<section id="About-us">
  <div id="left">
    <h1>Hola</h1>
    <p>My enterprise is a La mayoría de las veces, los elementos absolutamente posicionados que tienen su height y width establecidos en auto son ajustados hasta acomodarse a su contenido. Sin embargo, elementos non-replaced y absolutamente posicionados
      se pueden crear para llenar el espacio vertical disponible, especificando tanto top como bottom, y dejando height sin especificar (es decir, auto). De igual manera se pueden utilizar para llenar el espacio horizontal disponible especificando tanto
      left como right, y dando a width el valor de auto.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</section>
```

### Caso 2:

Para el segundo caso de ajuste de imagen tenemos el siguiente ejemplo:

```css
section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  background-color: rgb(239, 231, 226);
  width: 50%;
  font-size: calc(0.5rem + 0.5vw);
  height: 100vh;
}

#right {
  background-image: url(https://www.cic.es/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/industria-4.0-transformacion-digital.jpg);
  
  /* Se reemplazó «cover» por «center» */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
  /* Se elimina esta propiedad: */
  /* background-attachment: fixed; */
  
  /* Se reemplazó 100% 100vh por cover
     en el segundo caso */
  background-size: cover;
  
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<section id="About-us">
  <div id="left">
    <h1>Hola</h1>
    <p>My enterprise is a La mayoría de las veces, los elementos absolutamente posicionados que tienen su height y width establecidos en auto son ajustados hasta acomodarse a su contenido. Sin embargo, elementos non-replaced y absolutamente posicionados
      se pueden crear para llenar el espacio vertical disponible, especificando tanto top como bottom, y dejando height sin especificar (es decir, auto). De igual manera se pueden utilizar para llenar el espacio horizontal disponible especificando tanto
      left como right, y dando a width el valor de auto.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</section>
```

Si desea profundizar sobre el tema puede consultar:

1. [background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/background-position).
2. [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

> Pulse el enlace «Página completa» que se observa en la demo publicada acá.